# Pagination in jquery jtable show 1 2 3 NAN NAN 4

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jtable

I'm trying to display `10 records` per page but is hows the `NAN` values Below is the Code snippet

```
$('#JarDistHist').jtable('detach');
$('#JarDistHist').jtable({
            title: 'Jar Distribution History',
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            sorting: true,
            defaultSorting: 'Date ASC',
            actions: {
                listAction: 'StudentActions.php?action=list&DistId='+cname+'&fitem='+fitem+'',
                deleteAction: 'StudentActions.php?action=delete'
            },
            fields: {
                id: {

                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false,

                    },

                Date: {
                    title: ' Date',
                    type: 'date',
                     displayFormat: 'dd-mm-y',
                    width: '40%'


                },
                TotRecvJars: {
                    title: 'Rec. ',
                    width: '30%',
                    display: function (data) {
                     return $('<a href="JarFillingDetail.php?id=' + data.record.id + '">'+data.record.TotRecvJars+'</a>');

                     // return  $('<a href="JarFillingDetail.php?id=' + data.record.id + '">'+data.record.Date.format('DD-MM-YY')+');
                     }
                },
                NoOfJarsFill: {
                    title: 'Filled ',
                    width: '30%',
                    type:'integer',
                    display: function (data) {
                     return $('<a href="JarFillingDetail.php?id=' + data.record.id + '">'+data.record.NoOfJarsFill+'</a>');


                     }
                },

                BalanceJars: {
                    title: 'Bal. ',
                    width: '30%',
                    type:'integer',
                    display: function (data) {
                     return $('<a href="JarFillingDetail.php?id=' + data.record.id + '">'+data.record.BalanceJars+'</a>');


                     }
                }

            }
        });

        //Load person list from server
        $('#JarDistHist').jtable('load');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your column definitions you are saying `type: 'integer'` (NoOfJarsFill and BalanceJars), which means you want to display a number. But then you are returning HTML content as the value, which is not a number. "Not A Number" is exactly what NAN stands for.

Change `type: 'integer'` to `type: 'string'` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Chages done But no Sucess..The Default paging is 10 records per page but it shows showing 1 to 10 of undefined records..